# How to list all installed neo4j server plugins from web interface or shell?

Tags: neo4j

Right now I'm using the neo4jrestclient python package to list extensions:

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
ext = gdb.extensions
```

Is there a direct shell command I can use do this? I also don't see anything on the web interface. I'm using 1.8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
curl -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/
```

From the command line. Extensions aren't available on the web interface.

Answer (score 13):

Since this is the top answer in Google and the accepted answer is out of date for v3.0+, here's a new answer.

On [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/procedures/), they show a number of new procedures, and the one in question to get a list of all procedures in the database (including plugins) is "dmbs.procedures()", and I find it most useful to have the signature of the procedure as well as the name. The query for that is:

```
CALL dbms.procedures() YIELD name, signature RETURN name, signature
```

Comment: Will that list kernel extensions?

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions, it's

```
SHOW PROCEDURES yield name, description, signature
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the [extensions documentation](https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensions.html) for `neo4j-rest-client`:

```
>>> gdb.extensions
{u'GetAll': <Neo4j ExtensionModule: [u'get_all_nodes', u'getAllRelationships']>}

>>> gdb.extensions.GetAll
<Neo4j ExtensionModule: [u'get_all_nodes', u'getAllRelationships']>

>>> gdb.extensions.GetAll.getAllRelationships()[:]
[<Neo4j Relationship: http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/0>,
 <Neo4j Relationship: http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/1>,
 <Neo4j Relationship: http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/2>,
 <Neo4j Relationship: http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/3>]
```